# How to add liquidity for an inflationary cryptocurrency

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency, erc20

I have an NFT collection that generates 1 token (let's call them COIN) every 24 hours (see CyberKongz). There is no ICO for COIN and the currency is 100% inflationary meaning the supply starts when the first NFT generates 1 COIN.

If the price of each NFT is `.003 ETH` and I purchase COIN with `5%` of the proceeds from the sale, then the initial price after minting the first NFT would be `.003 ETH * .05(%) = 0.00015 ETH` or `50 cents USD`.

Since the NFT generates COIN every day, and multiple NFT's are minted on any given day, how do I properly add liquidity to COIN keeping its price to two decimal places? If I purchase COIN with the proceeds of the sale, does it essentially just become like an ICO where one wallet holds most of the coins?

Does anyone have a good suggestion for the monetary policy of COIN given its inflationary nature?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

well, that's how inflation works, but you can try using a kind of bot that listen all the events to know how much tokens was minted and make it do the math and decides when to add more liquidity and how much liquidity